# How to properly add a navbar at the top of the page using codeIgniter-bootstrap?

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using codeIgniter-bootstrap as my framework.

I keep getting a disoriented frontpage and my navbar isn't even coming out right. My navbar keeps going over my "hero unit". I'm using this as a sort of learning process to get familiar with the MVC concept. I'm not sure what is causing this disorientation.

Here's what my front page markup code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <title>CodeIgniter Bootstrap</title>

        <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/font-awesome.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/custom.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/1.3.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js') ?>"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/custom.js') ?>"></script>
    </head>
    <body>


    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="hero-unit">
                <h2>CodeIgniter Bootstrap</h2>
                <p>CodeIgniter Bootstrap kick starts the development process of the web development process by including Twitter Bootstrap into CodeIgniter. It also includes certain libraries such as AWS and Facebook in-case you are developing applications requiring those SDKs. So stop writing the same code over again and start working on your idea.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="https://github.com/sjlu/CodeIgniter-Bootstrap">View on Github</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Just looking at your HTML, you never close your first `<div class="container">`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are using bootstrap v3 , thats for v2.x try replacing menubar.php in your templates folder with this

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fadsel Technologies</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

> after that include it in your frontpage.php , You are good to go

```
  <div class="container" style="padding-top:30px;" >
```

......

```
<?php include('templates/menubar.php');
    ?>
```